# Django - storing a raw string literal in model for regex use?

Tags: regex, django, django-models

I have Django model and in one of the fields I need to store a regex string that I'll use later:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    regex_string = models.TextField()
```

So for example, the regex_string field might be set to:

```
r'\d{2}'
```

I then try to retrieve this later, compile it as a regex expression and use it - however, it doesn't seem to work as planned:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(ham.regex_string)
>>> print(pattern.match("22"))
None
```

Obviously if I pass the raw string literal in directly, it works fine:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\d{2}')
>>> pattern.match("22")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1505100>
```

If I actually print ham.regex_string, it returns:

```
u"r'\\d{2}'"
```

So it's a unicode string, but for some reason the backslashes are doubled-up? Is there a better way of storing a regex pattern in a Django model, so I can use it later?

Cheers,
Victor

EDIT: Thanks to everybody for their answers =). I've awarded the answer to rczajka, since he was first part the post (at least if StackOverflow timestamps are to be believed).

Just to clear things up, the field was entered in by users on a form (django-admin). Previously, they were entering in the regex **with** the `r''` - e.g. `r'\d{2}\`. However, if I just get them to enter in the string literal itself `\d{2}`, it now seems to work - Django doesn't tamper with the string, or interpret the backslashes - there's no reason it should, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you set the regex_string field? Do you perhaps put in an input on a page? The `r''` notation is merely syntactic sugar:

```
>>> r'\d{2}'
'\\d{2}'
>>> print r'\d{2}'
\d{2}
```

So if you want to put something in an input, write the actual regex string (`\d{2}`), not a Python literal.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to be more clever after retrieving it.

```
>>> import ast
>>> print ast.literal_eval(u"r'\\d{2}'")
\d{2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Er, don't store the literal (i.e. `"r'\d{2}'"`), store what it yields.

```
foo    = Foo.objects.create(regex_string = r'\d{2}')
foo_re = re.compile(foo.regex_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a really strange error. A Python raw string is just a syntactic convenience (it evaluates to a regular byte-string), so I don't see how it's even possible to get `u"r'\\d{2}"`. All I can think of is that you somehow wrote double quotes around the literal, which isn't a likely error.

When I run

```
from someproject.someapp.models import *
ham = Foo(name=u'test', regex_string=r'\d{2}')
ham.save()
ham = Foo.objects.get(name=u'test')
print ham.regex_string
```

in the `manage.py shell`, I get the Unicode string `\d{2}` (as expected).

You said you printed `ham.regex_string`, but it looks like you actually just evaluated it in the Python interactive console. This gives an object's `repr`, which in this case is `u'\\d{2}'`. The doubled `\\` is just for display; the string actually contains a single `\`.

Also: are you actually using the regex to match binary strings? If not, you should use a Unicode regex `ur'\d{2}'` instead. If you are, you should explicitly Base64-encode your regex, since in general a binary regex is not valid UTF-8 and will therefore not be stored correctly in the database.

Comment: It's possible if someone types "r'\d{2}'" into a `TextField`.